# How to create autoresizing NSTextView for printing?

Tags: cocoa, printing, nstextview

Here's what I want to do: generate a print view for a text with multiple paragraphs. On a side of each paragraph I want to have annotation text displayed.

So effectively in `drawRect` I need to create an instance of `NSTextView` (on the LHS) and corresponding `NSTextView` on its right. Which is followed by another pair, and so on and so on...

Question is, how do I create a text view that is limited in width, but unlimited in height? I know what the font is going to be used and its size, but the height also depends on the text wrapping, which I've no idea how to account for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to calculate the correct rect size you should use to create the new textview? If so, here's a method demonstrating how to use NSString's sizeWithAttributes method:

```
- (BOOL) doesString:(NSString *)string fitInRectOfSize:(NSSize)rectSize usingFont:(NSFont *)font {
    NSMutableDictionary *fontAttrs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSSize sizeFilled = [string sizeWithAttributes:fontAttrs];
    [fontAttrs release];
    if (sizeFilled.width <= rectSize.width && sizeFilled.height <= rectSize.height)
            return YES;
    else 
            return NO;
}
```

As for the text wrapping, if the text has been entered into an NSTextView, the string will have '\n' chars at the soft line breaks. If you leave those in, stringWithAttributes will take them into consideration.

Comment: a-ha! sizeWithAttributes is what I needed indeed, thank you! Apple dev docs are so confusing, not that they lack information, but just finding that information is difficult. BTW now that you pointed me to the right direction, I've managed to find the example that does just what I need: puts the text in width restrained, but unlimited height rectangle. Here's the link in case anyone needs it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992950/nsstring-sizewithattributes-content-rect

Comment: Glad I could supply the clue you needed, even if the final answer is a little beyond me. (Yes, it's hard to find specific solutions in the Apple dev docs; I usually search SO too.)